# adding one time to another mysql

Tags: mysql

Is there anyway in MySQL I can set a column to carry over when it reaches 60? At the moment I have say 7.45 hrs and I want to add 20 mins to it I get 7.75. The column is set to `decimal`. I tried setting it to `time` but it added seconds which I don't need.

Comment: You may not need the seconds, but it it a problem that they are there?

Comment: Thanks I may have to go that way.

Answer (score 1):

Good option is to use `Time` data type and then just discard seconds if you dont need that.
It will help you in future when you need any kind of calculations on that field.

you can use `ADDTIME` to your query to add the time in your time column as below.

```
SELECT ADDTIME(YourColumn,'0:20') FROM YourTable;
```

you also can use `TIME_FORMAT` to get the desired output (e.g. discard seconds)

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(YourColumn,'%H:%i') FROM TableName;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advise you to not use `decimal` for what you are trying to do, but using `time` instead.

Using `time`, you can make use of the many date and time functions like adding minutes.

There are multiple solutions to your problem.

1. Using the addtime() function:

   ```
   update tablename
   set timecolumn = addtime(timecolumn, '00:20:00');
   ```
2. Using interval:

   ```
   update tablename
   set timecolumn = timecolumn + interval 20 minute;
   ```
3. Using a combination of date_add() and interval:

   ```
   update tablename
   set timecolumn = date_add(timecolumn, interval 20 minute);
   ```

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: Thanks Dan. I changed everything to use the the time datatype